# OData API - 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: odata

Building in NopCommerce here.

Have an interesting question:

I am extending an existing API and adding a method which allow for pictures to be cleared from categories. The code below is justa stub of what I will implement. It's sitting in a CtageoryController

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ClearCategoryPictureLinks([FromBody] ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        var categoryId = (int)parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "categoryId").Value;

        return Ok(true);
    }
```

And I added some changes in the route provider for the API. The code between the two //... I added in.

```
public partial class ODataRouteProvider : IRouteProvider
{
    public int Priority => 10;

    public void RegisterRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
    {
        //OData
        var serviceProvider = routeBuilder.ServiceProvider;
        IEdmModel model = GetEdmModel(serviceProvider);
        routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100);
        routeBuilder.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
        routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
    }

            private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
        builder.Namespace = "Default";

        builder.EntitySet<Category>("Category");
        var category = builder.EntityType<Category>();
        builder.EntityType<Category>().Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().Page();
    
   //...

        var actionCategoryPictureClear = category.Collection.Action("ClearCategoryPictureLinks");
        actionCategoryPictureClear.Parameter<int>("categoryId");
        actionCategoryPictureClear.Returns<bool>();
        actionCategoryPictureClear.Namespace = typeof(Category).Namespace;

   //...

        var tt = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(
                    x => x.FullName.StartsWith("SevenSpikes")
                || x.FullName.StartsWith("Nop4you")
                || x.FullName.StartsWith("Nop.Services.")
                || (x.FullName.StartsWith("Nop.Plugin.") && !x.FullName.StartsWith("Nop.Plugin.Misc.OData"))
                )
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());

        builder.Ignore(types.ToArray());


        return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

}

Unfortunately, the action that I addded always returns 406 Not Acceptable error result when I call it from POST MAN.

URL: odata/category/ClearCategoryPictureLinks

Any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Comment: do the other actions work?

Answer (score 0):

After I rebuilt my solution, the issue went away. I'm not sure what the actual cause of that is other than the bin files not updating correctly in visual studio.